# I can not change the value of actual parameter in C when pass address of structure

Tags: c, malloc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct s{
    int n;
}F;

F* make();
void create(F *s);
void add(F *f);
void show(F *f);

int main()
{
    F *f=NULL;

    //1.) the following doesn't work
    create(f);
    show(f);


    //2.) The Following is work
    f=make();
    show(f);



    printf("Hello world!\n");
    return 0;
}

void add(F *f){
    (f->n)++;
}
void show(F *f){
    printf("\n======\n %d \n======\n",f->n);
}
F* make(){
    F * temp=(F*)malloc(sizeof(F));
    temp->n=19;
    return temp;
}
void create(F *s){
    F * temp=(F*)malloc(sizeof(F));
    temp=make();
    s=temp;
    show(s);
    }
```

Please explain if why the code fragment(1) says fragmentation fault ( I know it is about access to an invalid memory space but by looking to my own code, I don't know where the mistake is. ) ,but the (2) is ok, it work fine. Thank you in advance .

Answer (score 1):

The reason you're getting a seg fault is because the variable `f` in `main` is remaining `NULL`.

That's because in `create()` your assigning `temp` to your local variable `s`, which has nothing to do with `f` outside the function. If you want the function to modify where a pointer points, you'll need to pass a pointer to a pointer, ie. `F **s`.

Your `create()` function could then look something like:

```
void create(F **s){
    F * temp=(F*)malloc(sizeof(F));
    temp=make();
    *s=temp;
    show(*s);
}
```

And you would pass the address of `f` to `create()`:

```
create(&f);
```

`s` contains the address of `f`, and therefore modifying the value of `*s` is identical to modifying the value of `f`.

Comment: Thank you AusCBloke, I got it. Exactly as your said.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change `create()` to accept a pointer to pointer to `F` like this:

```
void create(F** s)
{
    F* temp = malloc(sizeof(F));
    *s = temp;
    show(*s);
}
```

Comment: create(&f);
with the " void created(F**s); pototype.

Answer (score 0):

```
 F *f=NULL;      //1.) the following doesn't work     
 create(f);
```

Passes the pointer ***by value*** to the function. The original pointer `f` is never allocated any memory. The function allocates memory to the copy of the pointer `f`. While, `f` still points to `NULL`. Eventually, You end up dereferencing the `NULL` pointer resulting in ***Undefined Behavior*** which manifests itself in the form of a segmentation fault.

You need to pass the pointer ***by reference*** to the function to allocate it memory:

```
 create(&f);
```

where:

```
void create(F **s);

void create(F **s)
{
    *s = malloc(sizeof(F));     
    show(*s); 
}
```